# Unable to run Shell script using nohup command

Tags: shell, hive

I am using below script for fetching the CREATE TABLE statement from Hive database.
The script runs fine from command prompt, but when trying to execute using nohup job gets stopped at the line running `/usr/bin/hive`.
Can someone please help?

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f tableNames_List.txt
rm -f HiveTableDDL_List.txt
hive --showHeader=false --silent=true --outputformat=csv2 -e "use devinstance"
hive --showHeader=false --silent=true --outputformat=csv2 -e "use devinstance;show tables;" > tableNames_List.txt
wait
cat tableNames_List.txt | while read LINE
   do
   /usr/bin/hive -e "use devinstance;show create table \`$LINE\`" >> HiveTableDDL_List.txt
   echo -e "; \n" >> HiveTableDDL_List.txt
   done
echo "Table DDL generated"
```

Comment: `**` formatting doesn't work in code blocks. Just use comments when you want to make something clear.

Comment: That said, `nohup` doesn't really do very much. `nohup yourscript &` is _exactly_ the same as `yourscript </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 & disown -h $!`

Comment: The most important change I'd make is to stop `/usr/bin/hive` from trying to read stdin. Putting `</dev/null` on that line will have the relevant effect.

Comment: As a minor performance optimization, also, consider taking out the `>>HiveTableDDL_List.txt` redirections, and replacing them with only one `>HiveTabelDDL_List.txt` _after the `done` (on the same line)_. You can also put `<tableNames_list.txt` after the `done` as well, and thus not need the `cat tableNames_List.txt |` either; that way your `while` loop runs inside the main shell instead of a subshell spawned for the pipeline. And using `>` instead of `>>` means you no longer need the `rm`s (you already can get rid of one of the two right now).

Comment: Hi Charles, As I am new to shell script, if you can make change in the code and paste it here, will be great help.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/b66830da99e619f94d074ee03735d595 as a starting point demonstrating the above suggestions (and also using a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) instead of a temporary file).

Comment: Getting below error:     Hive_Table_Creation.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
Hive_Table_Creation.sh: line 7: `done >> HiveTableDDL_List.txt < < (hive --showHeader=false --silent=true --outputformat=csv2 -e "use devinstance;show tables;")'

Comment: Are you running `sh yourscript`? It's a _bash_ script, it needs to be run with `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: Mind, there's no `<'` anywhere in the code I showed you. Be sure you're using it _exactly_ as-given.

Comment: Hive_Table_Creation.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
Hive_Table_Creation.sh: line 6: `done >> HiveTableDDL_List.txt < < (hive --showHeader=false --silent=true --outputformat=csv2 -e "use devinstance;show tables;")'

Comment: hi Charles, I copied the command again. It started working now. Thanks very prompt help.

Comment: It's not `< < (`, it's `< <(`. The spacing needs to be _exact_. Consider running both my original code and your modified version through http://shellcheck.net/